# Swift trouble with Doubles

Tags: swift, swiftui

Comments in code explain what is going wrong. I'm not sure why it is not working. Im assuming it has something to do with types. When I have just (count) print out and not (count!), I get something like Optional(5.0) but count! would print out just 5.0

```
struct ContentView: View {
    @StateObject var fitness = main()
    @State var final = HKActivitySummary()
    @State var WeekElevation = 0.0
    
    var body: some View {
        Button("refresh"){
            fitness.authorizeHealthkit()
            fitness.makeQuery() { (summary) in
                final = summary
            }
            @State var keeper : Double = 0.0
            fitness.makeElevationQuery { statisticsCollection in
                if let statisticsCollection = statisticsCollection {
                    let startDate = Calendar.current.date(byAdding: .weekOfYear, value: -1, to: Date())
                    let endDate = Date()
                    statisticsCollection.enumerateStatistics(from: startDate!, to: endDate) {
                        (statistics, stop) in
                        let count = statistics.sumQuantity()?.doubleValue(for: .count())
                        if (count != nil) {
                            print(count!) //Doubles with values are printed out here
                            keeper += count! // trying to add the double to keeper
                            print(keeper).   // always prints out 0.0 (count is not being added)
                            
                        }
                    }
                }
                
            }
        }
```

Comment: You shouldn't have any `@State var` within the scope of your body. Move it to the top with your other state variables.

Comment: Note that, your whole `fitness.makeElevationQuery {...}` is unlikely to work, because inside a view body, you must return a `View`, and fitness.makeElevationQuery {...}` does not do that. You cannot have this "normal" code anywhere you like in SwiftUI views. Do the tutorial again at: https://developer.apple.com/tutorials/swiftui/

Answer (score 2):

Here are a couple things to do.

First, move this line:

```
@State var keeper : Double = 0.0
```

so that it's at the top of the struct with the rest of your `@State var`'s (so that you're declaring it as a var on `ContentView`). Right now `keeper` is a local variable declared within the `Button`'s action, and won't be available after that function runs. `@State` doesn't work with local variables, and that's what's causing the issue. If you remove `@State` but leave everything about your code the same, you'll find that you can change the variable as expected.

Second, `count` is assigned a value then checked to see if it's nil. Swift has a better way to do this that avoids the force unwrap (with `!`):

```
if let count = statistics.sumQuantity()?.doubleValue(for: .count()) {
    // if count would have been nil, this won't execute
    // count now has type Double (not Optional<Double>), so you don't need to unwrap it
    keeper += count
}
```